GitLab Runner Authentication Failure - "fatal: Authentication failed for https:/***.com
I'm encountering an authentication error when running pipelines with GitLab Runner on an Ubuntu server. My code resides in a GitLab repository, and the runner is configured and running. I've verified the runner registration token is correct.
Problem:
Pushing code triggers a pipeline run, but it fails with the error: "fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://******.com'"

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Double-checked the runner registration token in the config.toml file.
Confirmed the runner is online and registered with GitLab in the project's CI/CD settings.
Verified the runner user has permissions to access the project's repository
Additional Information:
Ubuntu Server version (e.g., 24.04 LTS)
GitLab Runner version : 17-0-stable
GitLab project visibility (public/private)

Question:
What could be causing this authentication failure despite a seemingly correct configuration? Any additional troubleshooting steps are appreciated.

adding the clone_url as described in the docs fixed the problem for me.
url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"
clone_url = "https://gitlab.example.com/"

later on I realized that the problem's rootcause was an old value leftover in values.yaml.
For some reason global.hosts.https was false in there.
ie doublechecking the defined values is always a good idea.
